# Rails processing background jobs in real-time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, delayed-job

I use hirefire-gem with Delayed-Job 3 on heroku cedar-stack and it is working pretty good in terms of hiring/firing but performance of the job execution is terrible. firing up the background job and seeing the results in the UI takes about 5-8 seconds locally and about 25-30 seconds (!) on heroku.

Processing time of the jobs is about the same locally/deployed but hiring workers (scaling, up, starting, ...) seems to take a lot of time(?).

is that a common issue? is there a solution (rake tasks, etc.)?

Thanks a lot.
Best, Phil

Answer (score 0):

It's down to the fact that your worker isn't running all the time but spinning up for each individual job.  The lag is the code start-up time.

If you have a full time dyno the jobs should process almost instantaneously.

Comment: ok but since the number of parallel jobs should be (theoretically) infinite this isn't a solution... from a practical financial standpoint :-)

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  One full time worker can process a fair amount in a month, and only cost $35.